# How to add 1 more header in Angular Table

Tags: javascript, html, angular

[image: table]
I need to add one more column with colspan=4 above existing ones, it has got to be sticky, just like another header column. The code is here:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">            

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="all" sticky>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Все </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.all}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="done">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Выполнено </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.done}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ctrl">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> На контроле </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ctrl}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="rjct">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Отклонено </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rjct}} </td>
    </ng-container>    


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

How do I make it happen? I tried adding plain html, it didn't work out, just like adding another angular table element.

Finally, the layout should look something like this:
[image: need to be achieved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new `ng-container` for the column, and add a `colspan` attribute to the `th`, like so:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="grouped">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef colspan="4"> Grouped </th>
</ng-container>
```

This will ensure the row spans 4 columns.

Then, add the `tr` definition, like so:

```
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="groupedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
```

**[Here is an example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6jwvj?file=app/table-basic-example.html)**

Comment: Glad to help. If this has answered your question, please feel free to accept the answer with the green tick button to ensure others can find it in the future. Thanks